# HIDLIbrary compile error

Tags: c#, hid

```
HIDLibrary.HidDevice[] HidDeviceList;
HidDevice HidDevice;

// Enumerate the devices with the Vendor Id
// and Product Id of the IT4600
HidDeviceList = HidDevices.Enumerate(VID, PID);
```

This code fails in compile at the last line with this error

> Error 5   Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to
>   'HidLibrary.HidDevice[]'. An explicit conversion exists (are you
>   missing a cast?)

What cast do I need?

Comment: `HidDevices.Enumerate(VID, PID).ToArray()` or `.Cast<HidDevice>().ToArray()`  perhaps?

Comment: That's the solution Pink Floyd! Thanks.

If you could post it as a solution rather than a comment, I will upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message says, you cannot assign an `IEnumerable` to an array. You need to call `ToArray()` to turn your `IEnumerable` into an array. Since this is a non-generic implementation you most likely need to call `Cast<T>()` as well. It would look something like

`HidDeviceList = HidDevices.Enumerate(VID, PID).Cast<HidDevice>().ToArray();`

Comment: It works fine with

     HidDeviceList = HidDevices.Enumerate(VID, PID).ToArray();